# Loop thrugh StructureGroups with Razor MEdiator

Tags: razormediator

I would like to get the Root Structure Group and then iterate through all immediate children of it using the Razor Mediator.

Getting the root StructureGroup works, but it is a StructureGroupModel object.  Calling GetItems on this gives me an error.

Casting it to a StructureGroup object works, but calling GetItems on that also returns the same error about it being a property.  GetListItems does work (see code), but then I need to supply the ItemType filter, and that is quite challenging.

Questions:  Is it possible to iterate through the direct children of the Root StructureGroup in Razor?  How would I declare an ItemType filter to only the Structure Groups?

```
@{
    var rootSG = Publication.RootStructureGroup;
    <div>@rootSG.GetType()</div>
    var rootObject = TridionHelper.Engine.GetObject(rootSG.Id);
    <div>@rootObject</div>
    foreach (var sg in rootObject.GetListItems())
    {
        <div>@sg.OuterXml</div> @* this works.. *@
    }

}
```

Comment: Aren't you trying to do too much coding in a template here? This starts to look a bit like those ugly old VBScript Templates to me...

Comment: Haha...you do have a point!  We could also do this in a C# TBB, but what key value pair would you push to the package for the title and URL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try below code, I havn't run this though.

```
OrganizationalItemItemsFilter filter = new OrganizationalItemItemsFilter(TridionHelper.Engine.GetSession());
            filter.Recursive = true;
            filter.ItemTypes = new[] { ItemType.StructureGroup };
List<RepositoryLocalObject> SgItems = (List<RepositoryLocalObject>)rootObject.GetItems(filter);
```

// you can use GetListItems as well according to the need